# How to display date less that 1 month from getdate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a report that shows result based on period (e.g: 1 month period, 2 month period...). I try to query and come out like this. As i would like to get record 1 month from current date

```
SELECT printed_serial,[name],last_active_date
FROM #Temp t
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_micard] mi on mi.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch_cuid] chcu on chcu.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch] ch on ch.ch_id = chcu.ch_id
WHERE last_active_date <= DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())
```

with result:

```
card id    name    last_active_date 
0110       Sara    jan 4 2019 4:15 pm
0111       Ara     Nov 26 2013 12:22 am
```

but expected result :

```
card id    name    last_active_date 
0110       Sara    jan 4 2019 4:15 pm
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using mysql? Those brackets (`[]`) look like sql server.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: "1 month from current date" is not clear.  Please provide examples of the date period that you want.   Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff . example 1 month from currentdate(today's date) . it will show 4Jan 2019.. if 2 month from current date ( show 4 dec 2018)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - using date comparison between one month before and current date

```
SELECT printed_serial,[name],last_active_date
FROM #Temp t
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_micard] mi on mi.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch_cuid] chcu on chcu.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch] ch on ch.ch_id = chcu.ch_id
WHERE last_active_date >= DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())
and last_active_date <=getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really only interested in month and year, so you can use following:

```
SELECT printed_serial,[name],last_active_date
FROM #Temp t
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_micard] mi on mi.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch_cuid] chcu on chcu.cu_id = t.cu_id
INNER JOIN [dbfastsconfigdataref].[dbo].[cdf_ch] ch on ch.ch_id = chcu.ch_id
WHERE MONTH(last_active_date) = MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))
     AND YEAR(last_active_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))
```